# eglot + rust-analyzer: Failed to discover workspace

Tags: lsp-mode, rust, eglot

I've been having a really great experience w/ eglot for C++ development. I'm finding it a lot easier to use than lsp-mode (at least for C++). However, I'm running into an issue w/ both eglot (and lsp-mode, actually). `M-x eglot` when opening a rust source file gives:

```
[eglot] Server reports (type=1): Failed to discover workspace.
Consider adding the `Cargo.toml` of the workspace to the [`linkedProjects`](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual.html#rust-analyzer.linkedProjects) setti\
ng.

Failed to load workspaces.
```

NB: `lsp-mode` gives a similar error

First, it's a new project that has a Cargo.toml right in the root:

```
(base) mmessersmith@HP-ZBK-0425:~/repos/ruster$ tree
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── README.md
└── src
    └── main.rs
```

It cannot be rocket science to go and find that Cargo.toml file, so it seems like a really odd failure. I didn't do anything crazy here: I created the project w/ `cargo` like a normal person.

Secondly, where the heck is the config file the error message alludes to (on Ubuntu)? I can't find it. The only place I could find it was in their source code, so I re-built the `rust-analyzer` bin from source but changed that `linkedProjects` directory to point right to my `Cargo.toml` (e.g. changed the default in source): still no luck. I also tried randomly putting a `settings.json` in ~/.vscode-server/extensions/settings.json`, also no luck.

**How can I update such that I can get eglot to work with rust-analyzer?**

I am open to amending this mysterious config, wherever it may reside, but best solution I am looking for is to be able to auto-find the Cargo.toml.

There is nothing relevant here in my .emacs, so I won't list it. I'm just calling `M-x eglot` manually for now, no rust-mode hooks, etc.

**EDIT: Just created a *new* project and it seems to be working now. I will let this simmer though, in case someone else runs into this issue and there is a fix.**

Comment: Im getting the same with Dart. And I cant pinpoint what I changed,

Comment: Have you found a solution? How to specify `linkedProjects` for eglot?